# is it possible to click a button at a specific time using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, timing, milliseconds

I'm trying to time a button click event to the millisecond using jQuery by using global. It checks the time every 5 seconds, for example `00:00:20.05`. I managed to time it to the seconds but it doesn't have a consistent millisecond. Is it possible to do this?

```js
setInterval(function() {
  myfunction();
}, 5000);

function myfunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var ms = d.getMilliseconds();

  if (m == 20) {
    if (s == 00) {
      if (ms > 50) {
        x.click();
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
          checkMiliSecond();
        }, 50);
      }
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        checkSecond();
      }, 100);
    }
  }
}

function checkSecond() {
  var d = new Date();
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var ms = d.getMilliseconds();

  if (s == 00) {
    if (ms > 50) {
      x.click();
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        checkMiliSecond();
      }, 50);
    }
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      checkSecond();
    }, 100);
  }
}

function checkMiliSecond() {
  var d = new Date();
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
  var ms = d.getMilliseconds();

  if (ms > 50) {
    x.click();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      checkMiliSecond();
    }, 50);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. The timers don't block the event queue for the Browser so some other process may take precedence and you can't guarantee it to be on target to the millisecond.